# Why do my function return character(0) even though there is no error in the code?

Tags: r

I am seeking help on this function I have created. The purpose of this function: First, I want to extract a column from a data frame and arrange it in descending order. Then, I rank each element by "H", "M" and "L". I want to rank them such as the first 33% of the items should have the tag "H" and the last 33% of the items are tagged as "L". The rest should be tagged as "M".

This is the code:

```
ranking_prod <- function(data, column) {

  data <- arrange(data, desc(column))
  size <- length(data$column)
  first_third <- data$column[round(size / 3)]
  last_third <- data$column[round(size - (size / 3))]
  
  case_when(data$column > first_third ~ "H",
            data$column < last_third ~ "L",
            TRUE ~ "M")
}
```

However, when I apply this function to the following data frame:

```
> one <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
> two <- c(1, 2, 2, 1, 5)
> three <- c(2, 2, 2, 4, 5)
> dataframe <- data.frame(one, two, three)
```

It returns:

```
> rank_volume(dataframe, two)
character(0)
```

Where is the error in the code? Why is it displaying character(0) as the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `[[` instead of `$` and also as we are passing unquoted argument, convert to string.  As we are converting to `sym`bol with `ensym`, the input can either be unquoted or quoted

```
ranking_prod <- function(data, column) {

  column <- rlang::ensym(column)
  colstr <- rlang::as_string(column)
  data <- dplyr::arrange(data, desc(!!column))
  size <- length(data[[colstr]])
  first_third <- data[[colstr]][round(size / 3)]
  last_third <- data[[colstr]][round(size - (size / 3))]
  
  dplyr::case_when(data[[colstr]] > first_third ~ "H",
            data[[colstr]] < last_third ~ "L",
            TRUE ~ "M")
}
```

-testing

```
ranking_prod(dataframe, two)
#[1] "H" "M" "M" "L" "L"
ranking_prod(dataframe, 'two')
#[1] "H" "M" "M" "L" "L"
```