# Error reappearing with similar code (which initially works) in Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

I recently wrote a code for my shiny app but accidentally deleted some parts of it. The codes were working previously. However, when I try to recover the codes by retyping it again and run the app, the old issues came back.

First, this is a dataset that I used as testing for my app:

```
> data
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  `product id` amount `total sales`
  <chr>         <dbl>         <dbl>
1 X180             20           200
2 X109             30           300
3 X918             20           200
4 X273             15           150
5 X988             12           120
```

Now, I am trying to make an app where the users will import their own excel file, select the relevant columns and the app will clean up the data and apply an additional function with mutate. It will then return the new table. How the function works can be found here, in case it is relevant: [Why do my function return character(0) even though there is no error in the code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67677725/why-do-my-function-return-character0-even-though-there-is-no-error-in-the-code/67677754#67677754)

This is my code for the app:

```
## load packages
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(rlang)
library(ggplot2)

## the function to be applied to the dataset
rank_volume <- function(data, column) {
  
  column <- ensym(column)
  colstr <- as_string(column)
  data <- arrange(data, desc(!!column))
  size <- length(data[[colstr]])
  first_third <- data[[colstr]][round(size / 3)]
  last_third <- data[[colstr]][round(size - (size / 3))]
  
  case_when(data[[colstr]] > first_third ~ "H",
            data[[colstr]] < last_third ~ "L",
            TRUE ~ "M")
}

## Here, users will be able to import their excel file, select which sheets to use, how many
## rows to skip, and a drop down list of all the columns' names to be selected to be used, 
## alongside with an actionButton.

ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput("df1", "Import File", accept = ".xlsx"),
  textInput('df1sheet', 'Sheet Name (Case-Sensitive)'),
  numericInput('df1skip', 'Skip rows', value = 0),
  uiOutput("pcode"),
  uiOutput("nsales"),
  actionButton("update", "Generate Result"),
  tableOutput("vmtable"))


## Server section with renderUI for selectInput, and eventReactive function for the actionButton. 
## Also a renderTable function which will perform the cleanup and apply function 
## according to which columns of dataset the users chose.

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  data1 <- reactive({
    req(input$df1)
    req(input$df1sheet)
    read_excel(input$df1$datapath, sheet = input$df1sheet, skip = input$df1skip)
  })
  
  output$pcode <- renderUI({
    selectInput("productcode", "Product Code", choices = names(data1()))
  })
  
  output$nsales <- renderUI({
    selectInput("netsales", "Net Sales", choices = names(data1()))
  })
  
  pc <- eventReactive(input$update, {
    input$productcode
  })
  
  ns <- eventReactive(input$update, {
    input$netsales
  })
  
  output$vmtable <- renderTable({
    data2 <- data1() %>% 
      select(`Product Code` = input$pc, `Net Sales` = input$ns) %>%
      replace_na(list(`Net Sales` = 0)) %>%
      arrange(., desc(`Net Sales`))%>%
      mutate(Volume = rank_volume(., `Net Sales`))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The error I received after I imported the excel file:

```
Warning: Error in : arrange() failed at implicit mutate() step.                                                                           
* Problem with `mutate()` column `..1`.
ℹ `..1 = Net Sales`.
x object 'Net Sales' not found
  119: <Anonymous>
```

I do not think that the error comes from any part other than the `renderTable()` function. However, I'm pretty new to Shiny so I may have made an error in other parts of the code. I am sorry if the codes are too long. I apologise for any inconvenience but I would be glad if anyone can give me some help on this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is based on how you are calling `eventReactive` objects.  Replace this line

```
select(`Product Code` = input$pc, `Net Sales` = input$ns) %>%
```

with this line

```
select(`Product Code` = pc(), `Net Sales` = ns()) %>%
```